# Convert ansible dictionary list values to keys and keys to values

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have a scenario where I need to convert this dictionary `dict1` into `dict2` in an Ansible playbook as shown below

```py
dict1 = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}

dict2 = {1: 'a', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'b', 5: 'b', 6: 'b'}
```

I tried `with_nested`, `with_items` but wasn't able to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit ugly but does the job without having to use `set_fact` in a task which gives you freedom to declare the var anywhere (e.g. inventory, playbook, role defaults or vars, external file...).

The solution uses `json_query` (which needs additional collection and pip module install on the controller, see [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries)) because `items2dict` is not able to use nested elements as key/value references.

`map('flatten')` in the solution is a workaround for a "bug" in jmespath (library used by `json_query`) which is unable to directly address tuples returned by `subelements`: it transforms each element into a list where indexes can correctly be used in `json_query`

I did not spend time to see if indexes could be transformed to ints like asked in your requirement. As is, the final `items2dict` transforms them back to string representations. If this is not acceptable you will have to search further.

Note: the below example will work in ansible >= 2.10. With an older version you will have to stick some intermediate `list` filters inside the `dict2` expression.

The playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    dict1: {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]}
    transform_q: >-
      [*].{"key": [1], "value": [0].key}
    dict2: "{{ dict1 | dict2items | subelements('value') | map('flatten')
      | json_query(transform_q) | items2dict }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: dict2
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dict2": {
        "1": "a",
        "2": "a",
        "3": "a",
        "4": "b",
        "5": "b",
        "6": "b"
    }
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: This is awesome and thanks for your solution

Answer (score 1):

**update**

The below expression

```yaml
  dict2: |
    {% filter combine %}
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for k,v in dict1.items() %}
    - {{ dict(v|product(k)) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  dict2:
    1: a
    2: a
    3: a
    4: b
    5: b
    6: b
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    dict1: {a: [1, 2, 3], b: [4, 5, 6]}
    dict2: |
      {% filter combine %}
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for k,v in dict1.items() %}
      - {{ dict(v|product(k)) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: dict2
```

---

**origin**

The below *set_fact* gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dict2: "{{ dict2|d({})|
                   combine(dict(item.value|product([item.key]))) }}"
      loop: "{{ dict1|dict2items }}"
```